# Does Paelleall's Wrath of the Volcano ability affect Heroes on her tile and the Entrance Tile?

Tags: dungeon-run

Paelleall's Summoner Ability reads (**emphasis** mine):

> Wrath of the Volcano
>
> At the beginning of your turn, choose the shortest path from your current tile to the Dungeon Entrance tile. **All other heroes** within that path receive one wound marker. If multiple paths exist, choose 1.

Clearly her ability should affect heroes that share a dungeon tile with her, or they wouldn't have noted "All other heroes." Does reasoning follow that heroes on the Dungeon Entrance would be wounded as well?

**Is this path inclusive of the start and end point?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you cannot get any more definitive than the [designer himself, Mr. Bistro](http://boardgamegeek.com/article/8926389#8926389):

> Q: Is Paelleall's Wrath of the Volcano ability include hitting all other heroes on Paelleall's current tile, and any figures standing on the Entrance Tile as well? I would assume that it does, but it isn't clear to me.
>
> A: Yes, that is the intent. Every tile in the path is hit.